# Benchmarks of PHP ORMs? or Good Test Cases

Tags: php, orm, benchmarking

Are there any good performance benchmarks published out there for available PHP ORMs, such as Doctrine, Propel, and Outlet?

If not, what are some good test cases so I can test them myself?

Other ORMs I'd be interested in comparing:

- phpDataMapper
- dORM
- GacelaPHP
- pdoMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine is one of the most well regarded PHP base ones out there. But you can't really benchmark ORMs. All of them will have performance issues when they create a useless JOIN or a bad query, which all of them will do eventually.

In the end, they all just try to create a SQL query for you. How well they do it, is the difference. It's worthwhile to learn SQL if you have more than a few basic tables.

Comment: Even though I agree - but SO, for example, uses linq2sql. Yes, it is not actually an ORM, but it generates queries.

Comment: Good point. I guess I'd be interested in the strengths and weaknesses of each, and particularly how they fair at basic ORM'ing. :) In other words, how long does it take to e.g., compile a query and pass it to the underlying DB engine, load the results into objects, and access the data therein? Surely this is quantifiable?

Comment: While ORMs compiling/building the query adds overhead, it's minimal and would fall under micro-optimization. Loading result as objects as opposed to in array would add overhead, especially with memory. But in general these aren't things you need to worry about now.

Comment: I think that's my real answer. Anyway, I prefer to use an ORM mainly for convenience in handling the data, not because I can't write the SQL myself. It's a performance trade-off from the beginning, most definitely. Great advice, thanks Brent.

Comment: SO doesn't use Linq2Sql anymore, it uses the Dapper micro-ORM to replace the  performance penalties encountered with Linq2Sql

Answer (score 0):

You could try this test suite, also here are the results as of 09/2011:
http://code.google.com/p/php-orm-benchmark/

What I have found out by running own tests with own basic ORM implementation, it adds cca 30% overhead in execution time, and cca 80% in number of function calls.